# Why is size of bytes bigger than the original file?

Tags: python, binary, compression, huffman-code

I am trying to convert a pdf to binary format using python. However, I realized that the binary format has a bigger size than the file. Is there a reason for this? Or am I doing it wrong?

book.pdf size: 4,672,474 bytes,
binary size: 11,302,404 bytes

```
with open("book.pdf", "rb") as f:
    f = f.read()
    b = bytearray(f)
    bn_str = "".join(format(ord(i), "08b") for i in str(b))
print(len(bn_str) / 8)
```

I was expecting to get the same size after converting to binary. However, it appeared to have 2~3 times bigger size.

Comment: Have you checked what `str(b)` returns? Or compared `len(str(b))` with `len(b)`? You definitely _don't_ want a UTF-8 encoded escape-sequence-representation of the bytes, which is what you're currently working with.

Comment: Why are you iterating over `str(b)`???  you can just do `bn_str = "".join([forma(i, '08b') for in in b]` which is I think what you want. iterating over a `bytearray` or `bytes` object *already gives you* the byte value, note, `ord` isn't the exact same thing, that will give you the *unicode code point*.

Comment: And note, this isn't really *converting to a binary format*. `b = bytearray(f)` is in a binary format. You are creating some string representation of binary digits.

Comment: Why do you think that converting every byte into 8 bytes is going to make the file smaller?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the unexpected size is that `str(b)` creates a printable string representation of the binary array with a mix of ASCII characters and escaped binary chars resulting in a much larger string. `f.read()` returns a byte sequence instance which can be iterated over directly.

Try something like this:

```
with open("book.pdf", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(len(data))
    bn_str = "".join(format(i, "08b") for i in data)
    print(len(bn_str)//8)
```

bn_str will be 8x the size of the original file since each byte will be represented by a 8-byte character sequence of 1 and 0s.

The first four bytes of a PDF file should be "%PDF" so the binary output a PDF file would start with 00100101 01010000 01000100 01000110.